# How to do a simple plot with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to do a simple plot with pandas but get this error:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas

df = pandas.read_csv("volvo_volvo.csv");
dfw = pandas.DataFrame(data = df, columns=['PriceDisplay','Year','Odometer'])
y = df.PriceDisplay.values
x = df.Odometer.values

df.plot(x=x, y=y, marker='.')
plt.show()
```

IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds

CSV file columns price and odometer :

```
PriceDisplay    IsBold  Make    Transmission    Category    Owners  HasFreeShipping Year
17985   TRUE    Audi    Automatic   0001-0268-0271- 0   TRUE    2005
17985   TRUE    Audi    Automatic   0001-0268-0271- 0   TRUE    2005
17985   TRUE    Audi    Automatic   0001-0268-0271- 0   TRUE    2005
17985   TRUE    Audi    Automatic   0001-0268-0271- 0   TRUE    2005
17985   TRUE    Audi    Automatic   0001-0268-0271- 0   TRUE    2005
17985   TRUE    Audi    Automatic   0001-0268-0271- 0   TRUE    2005
17985   TRUE    Audi    Automatic   0001-0268-0271- 0   TRUE    2005
17985   TRUE    Audi    Automatic   0001-0268-0271- 0   TRUE    2005
17985   TRUE    Audi    Automatic   0001-0268-0271- 0   TRUE    2005
17985   TRUE    Audi    Automatic   0001-0268-0271- 0   TRUE    2005
17985   TRUE    Audi    Automatic   0001-0268-0271- 0   TRUE    2005
17985   TRUE    Audi    Automatic   0001-0268-0271- 0   TRUE    2005
17985   TRUE    Audi    Automatic   0001-0268-0271- 0   TRUE    2005
17985   TRUE    Audi    Automatic   0001-0268-0271- 0   TRUE    2005

Odometer
61988
61988
61988
61988
61988
61988
61988
61988
61988
61988
61988
61988
61988
61988
```

print out of the x and y variables :

print(x)

print(y)

```
[61988 61988 61988 61988 61988 61988 61988 61988 61988 61988 61988 61988
 61988 61988]
[17985 17985 17985 17985 17985 17985 17985 17985 17985 17985 17985 17985
 17985 17985]
```

Comment: Have you tried to add some print statements to see what's in your x and y variables? There are 2 columns in your file, but you are reading in three.

Comment: What are the `PriceDisplay` and `Year` fields? They are missing from your csv sample.

Comment: @MartinEvans added above

Comment: @roadrunner66 hey added above, yeah sorry ignore the third

Comment: What are you actually trying to plot?  Your code shows you trying to plot `PriceDisplay` against `Odometer`, which if you look at the data would just give you a single dot.

Comment: You call `df.plot`, I would expect it to be `plt.plot`?

Comment: @MartinEvans I just want the code to run with this dummy variable data

Comment: I got it working using plt.scatter(x,y,linewidth=2)
plt.show()
savefig('foo.png', bbox_inches='tight')
fig.savefig('fig2.bmp') I added a save part which doesnt save, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just leave out the `.values` in your assignments for `x` and `y`.